Does this result above six points follow have a name?

Does this result above six points follow have a name?


Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ be six points in the plane and $AB, CF, ED$ are concurrent and  $BC, DA, FE$ are concurrent then $CD, EB, AF$ are concurrent.


Can generalized of this result to higher dimensional spaces?



That is the dual of Pappus Theorem i believe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem.
